# Play! 2.0 hangs on "Application Started (dev)" after compile no errors

Tags: compiler-construction, playframework-2.0

Seems like just yesterday I had this same problem with Play! v1. After trying everything I could think of, I am out of ideas as to what could cause Play! to just hang on the `[info] play - Application started (Dev)`

- Using JDK 1.6
- Windows 7

Here's a screenshot of what's persisting:

[image: Play! hangs on compile no errors]

And that's the story of my life. Does anyone know of a bug with v2 or have any ideas?

**Update:** Discovered this is only occuring in Dev mode...but that's still important ;)

Comment: Can you add a bit more info? Especially things that differe between dev, and deployment.

Comment: strangely i didn't change anything with the src files and i tried `play clean` multiple times before trying PROD mode. it's late now but in the morning i'll run the windows equivalent of `strace` and see if there's something blocking the thread. i'll scan to see if there's any big differences but i didn't program any dev/prod modes into the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, and it's a possible bug.

Discovered that the app hangs on the screen above when the server process file isn't cleaned up. So to get past this (for my particular case) you need to go to the root of your app and delete `RUNNING_PID` file.